# How to prove $\binom{-r}{k} = (-1)^k \binom{r + k - 1}{k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I encountered the following problem in Brualdi (Section 5.6, Problem 21):

Prove that, for all real numbers $r$ and all integers $k$,

$$\binom{-r}{k} = (-1)^k \binom{r + k - 1}{k}$$

It looks like the right hand side has the formula for choosing $k$ elements from a multiset.

$$\binom{r + k - 1}{k} = \binom{r + k -1}{k - 1}$$

I know that $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ if $n < k$, but what if $k$ is negative and $n$ is a real number. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try expanding the LHS.

Answer (score 5):

$$\binom{-r}{k} =$$

$$ \frac {(-r)(-r-1)(-r-2)...(-r-k+1)}{k!}=$$

$$(-1)^k \frac {(r+k-1)(r+k-2)...(r+1)(r)}{k!}=$$

$$(-1)^k\binom{r+k-1}{k}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{\overbrace{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}^{k \text{terms}} }{k!}
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{-r}{k}=\frac{(-r)(-r-1)\cdots(-r-k+1)}{k!}=(-1)^{k} \frac{(r+k-1)!}{k!(r-1)!} =(-1)^{k}\binom{r+k-1}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

The starting definition of the binomial coefficients, for general complex argument values, is:

$${n \choose k} \equiv \frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (n-k+1)}.$$

(Note that this ratio is undefined for non-positive integers $n$ or $k$.)  Using this formula we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
{-r \choose k} =\frac{\Gamma (1-r)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (1-r-k)} &= \frac{\Gamma (1-r)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (1-r-k)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma (r)}{\Gamma (r)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma (r+k)}{\Gamma (r+k)} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma (r+k)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (r)} \cdot \frac{\Gamma (1-r) \Gamma (r)}{\Gamma (1-r-k) \Gamma (r+k)} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma (r+k)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (r)} \cdot \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi r)} \Bigg/ \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi (r+k))} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma (r+k)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (r)} \cdot \frac{\sin (\pi (r+k))}{\sin (\pi r)} \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\Gamma (r+k)}{\Gamma (k+1) \Gamma (r)} \cdot (-1)^k \\[8pt]
&= (-1)^k {r+k-1 \choose k}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(The third line of this working is using [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the gamma function.)  This completes the proof for all cases where the gamma function is well-defined.  The remaining cases involving $r = 0, 1, 2, ...$ and $k = 0, -1, -2, ...$ are generally resolved by extending the definition of the binomial coefficients using this very formula (in which case the formula holds by definition).

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3689.pdf) on the binomial coefficients with negative arguments might also assist you.